# Error in installation of dependencies in ionic

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I want to install angular@1.3.0 in node.js 6.10.0 but installation using command `npm install angular@1.3.0` gives the following error.

```
q@1.0.0 C:\Users\username
`-- angular@1.3.0

npm WARN q@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN q@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

What may be the probable reason?

Comment: Doesn't look like an error at all. Looks like it installed. Look at your node modules folder for it

Comment: Provide description and repository of your project in package.json. To get rid of this warning during next installation, add "private": true to package.json